# send property value to server after stabilization

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, client-server

I have some code that looks like this:

```
class MyVM : VMBase {
  public MyVM(IMyServerProxy proxy) {
    _proxy = proxy;
    _proxy.ValueChanged += OnValueChangedFromServer;
  }
  private void OnValueChangedFromServer(int value){
    _value = value;
    RaisePropertyChanged(() => Value);
  }
  public int Value { // bound to slider
    get { return _value; }
    set {
      _value = value;
      // need something here to only send stable values to server
      _proxy.ModifyValue(value); // async
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is this: Value is bound up to a slider control. That slider triggers a lot of changes. I don't want to send all those to the server. I only want to send the stable value. Essentially, I want to insert something into the Value setter that only calls the proxy after the Value has not changed for a full second. (I have a secondary concern that the server will route an out-of-date value change back to me, but I think that would be mostly mitigated if I just delay on my send to the server.)

I looked into using the `Task.Delay` method. However, it throws an exception if I cancel the delay, and constructing a new `CancellationSource` on every update didn't seem ideal either. Is there some better way?

Comment: @EugenePodskal, with your proposal the first change will always get sent. It would also imply that some property is getting set regularly, which it is not. I don't think it would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After considering a variety of options, including Rx extensions, I went with the `System.Threading.Timer` class. The class restarts its timer when you call its `Change` method.

Fields:

```
private readonly System.Threading.Timer _valueUpdater;
private bool _sendingValue;
```

in Constructor:

```
_valueUpdater = new System.Threading.Timer(OnSendValue, null, System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite, 0);
```

the Callback:

```
private void OnSendValue(object state)
{
     _proxy.ModifyValue(_value).Wait();
    _sendingValue = false;
    if (_isDisposed)
        _valueUpdater.Dispose();
}
```

the Setter:

```
_value = value;
_sendingValue = true;
_valueUpdater.Change(DelayMs, 0);
```

Destructor:

```
private bool _isDisposed;
public void Dispose()
{
    _isDisposed = true;

    if (!_sendingValue)
        _valueUpdater.Dispose();
...
```

Answer (score 1):

This technique falls into the category of logic called "event coalescing". Probably the implementation with the most minimal footprint is as follows:

```
class MyVM : VMBase {
  private bool _isChangePending = false;

  public MyVM(IMyServerProxy proxy) {
    _proxy = proxy;
    _proxy.ValueChanged += OnValueChangedFromServer;
  }

  private void OnValueChangedFromServer(int value){
    _value = value;
    RaisePropertyChanged(() => Value);
  }

  public int Value { // bound to slider
    get { return _value; }
    set {
      lock(_isChangePending) {
        _value = value;
        // only send send "stable" values to server
        if (!_isChangePending){
          _isChangePending = true;
          System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate {
            this.SendAfterStabilize(value);
            }, null);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  private void SendAfterStabilize(int lastChangedValue) {
    while (true) {
      System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);  // control coalescing delay here
      lock(_isChangePending) {
        if (_value == lastChangedValue) {
          _isChangePending = false;
          _proxy.ModifyValue(lastChangedValue); // async
          return;
        }
        else {
          lastChangedValue = _value;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that the `lock() { }` blocks are technically necessary to guarantee that every possible last change made (regardless of timing) would always reach the server by one second later. If you remove the `lock() { }` blocks, the code will still work 99.99% of the time, but very rarely, the last change made may not ever be sent to the server (due to lack of memory access synchronization between the threads).

Answer (score 1):

In .NET Framework 4.5 or higher you could use [BindingBase.Delay Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.delay%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in your `Slider` control:

```
<Slider Value="{Binding Value, Delay=1000}"
```

Comment: I don't think this will work in my scenario because I have several other text fields bound up to the Value. I want them all to update as the slider is moving. I could bind those to the slider control's value instead of the view model Value, but I have low confidence; binding to bindings has failed me on many occasions.